# Error When add a 'Done' button to numpad keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8, xcode6

So, the numpad keyboard doesn't come with a 'Done' button by default so I'd like to add one. In iOS 7 and below there were some tricks to add a button to the keyboard but they don't seem to be working in iOS 8.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad){
        textField.inputAccessoryView=self.toolBar; ///self.toolBar is a IBOutlet of UIToolBar and in this toolBar have a button 'Done'.

}
```

when run this code, application will terminated and give Error:

```
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:
<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7b283d20> should have parent view controller:
<HJ_PCreateUpdateCareTeamVC: 0x7a79bfc0> but requested parent is:
<UIInputWindowController: 0x7b9c9200>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did :

```
 textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:textField];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;


UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *doItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doDone)];
[toolBar setItems:@[doItem]];


textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

/// It is ok

Comment: -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    
    if(textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad){
       
        UIToolbar *toolBar1 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        UIBarButtonItem *doItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(tappedDoneBtn:)];
        [toolBar1 setItems:@[doItem]];
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar1;
      }
    return YES;
}

After this application will not terminated but only toolBar is visible for us.